# Quit PYTHON app with raw_input()

Tags: python

I've made a console app that allows me to talk with someone else on a personal chat. I want to allow both user to end the connection when they type quit.

Mind that even when the user close the terminal the port is still listening.

```
import socket
import threading

bind_ip = "0.0.0.0"
bind_port = 8887

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server.bind((bind_ip,bind_port))

server.listen(5)

print "[*] Listening on %s:%d" % (bind_ip, bind_port)

def handle_client(client_socket):

    while True:

        client_socket.send(raw_input('\n'))
        request = client_socket.recv(1024)
        print "[*] Received: %s" % request

        if exit == "exit":
            client_socket.close()

while True:

    client, addr = server.accept()

    print "[*] Accepted connection from %s:%d" % (addr[0], addr[1])

    client_handler = threading.Thread(target=handle_client,args=(client,))
    client_handler.start()
```

Answer (score 4):

You have multiple problems here.

- The remote user can't quit by typing `'quit'` because you're checking for `'exit'` instead of `'quit'`.
- You're not checking `request`, which is his actual request; you're checking `exit`, which is a function object, which is never going to be equal to any string.
- You call `client_socket.close()`, but you don't `break` out of the loop, so it'll just go right back around to the top of the loop.
- Although you claim that checking `raw_input` is "exactly what I've done", you're not doing it. The is the only place you call `raw_input` is in `client_socket.send(raw_input('\n'))`, and you're clearly not checking anything there.

So, to fix all of those problems:

```
while True:
    msg = raw_input('\n')
    if msg == "quit":
        break
    client_socket.send(msg)
    request = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print "[*] Received: %s" % request    
    if request == "quit":
        break
client_socket.close()
```

There are other very big problems in your design and code, but fixing these 4 will at least get you to the next one.

Comment: it closes the connection but changed the output, it doens't work as a chat anymore. The host has to send msg before receiving the msg from the client and its all mixed up

Comment: @SergeySozonov: As I said, there are other very big problems in your design and code. It was _already_ true that the host has to send a message before receiving from the client, and it's still true. It was also already true that you can only exchange messages one-by-one; you can't send two messages without waiting for a reply in between. And that your `request` can end up with multiple messages concatenated together, or half a message (which will also break the `quit` handling). And so on. My fixes for these 4 problems don't fix all those other problems.